# What is the difference between Map Reduce and Spark about engine in Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

It looks like there are two ways to use spark as the backend engine for Hive.

The first one is directly using `spark` as the engine. Like this [tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started).

Another way is to use `spark` as the backend engine for `MapReduce`. Like this [tutorial](https://github.com/sciencepal/dockers/tree/master/hadoop_hive_spark_docker).

In the first tutorial, the `hive.execution.engine` is `spark`. And I cannot see `hdfs` involved.

In the second tutorial, the `hive.execution.engine` is still `mr`, but as there is no `hadoop` process, it looks like the backend of `mr` is spark.

Honestly, I'm a little bit confused about this. I guess the first one is recommended as `mr` has been deprecated. But where is the `hdfs` involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood it differently.

Normally Hive uses MR as execution engine, unless you use IMPALA, but not all distros have this.

But for a period now Spark can be used as execution engine for Spark.

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/07/apache-hive-on-apache-spark-motivations-and-design-principles/  discusses this in more detail.

Comment: Could you provide some information about how is Spark engine different from MR engine?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your updating. Let's wait for two days to see if there is any other answer.

Comment: Sure, there is also TEZ as execution engine.

Comment: LoL, sorry sometimes I just forget something. And for others, finally, I just give up using Hive but use spark directly.

Comment: Impala on top of Hive (with Kudu) also works well. But need Cloudera for that.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Spark builds DAG(Directed acyclic graph) whereas Mapreduce goes with native Map and Reduce. While execution in Spark, logical dependencies form physical dependencies.

Now what is **DAG**?

DAG is building logical dependencies before execution.(Think of it as a visual graph)
When we have multiple map and reduce or output of one reduce is the input to another map then DAG will help to speed up the jobs.
[image] 
DAG is build in Tez (right side of photo) but not in MapReduce (left side).

**NOTE:**
Apache Spark works on DAG but have stages in place of Map/Reduce. Tez have DAG and works on Map/Reduce. In order to make it simpler i used Map/Reduce context but remember Apache Spark have stages. But the concept of DAG remains the same.

**Reason 2:**
Map persists its output to disk.(buffer too but when 90% of it is filled then output goes into disk) From there data goes to merge.
But in Apache Spark intermediate data is persist to memory which makes it faster. 
[Check this link for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334598/what-does-in-memory-data-storage-mean-in-the-context-of-apache-spark)